# McLaurin series of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

I've got a function $g(z) = \frac {(1-z)(e^z + e^{-z})}{e^z - e^{-z}}$.

I have to find coefficients $c_0, c_1, c_2, c_3$ of McLaurin's series of function $g$ (which is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n z^n $).

So I thought that it would be easier to see that $g(z) = (1-z) \coth(z) $.
But in the beginning I encountered a problem.

I know that $c_0 = g(0)$. But $\coth(0) = \infty$. What to do with that? What will  be $c_0$ equal to? Can you help?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want the *Laurent* series?

Comment: Well, it says Mclaurin's...

Comment: Your function is not holomorphic on any neighbourhood of $0$, so it doesn't have a Maclaurin series.

Comment: @Anne If it says "McLaurins" then either that is a mistake or the function is a mistake.  Not every function automatically as a McLaurins series, as per mrf's comment above.

Comment: Ok, it turned out that there was a mistake in the exercise- the proper question is how to find Laurent series of this. So, anyway, how to do it? So far, I only have been finding Laurent series of functions that could be easily written as geometric series, but here...?

Comment: @Anne -- do you have an answer yet about constructing the Laurent series?

Comment: @Anne I wrote it below.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the coth $\theta$ doesn't work is that the denominator of g(x) is 0 at x = 0.  Changing it to coth doesn't change the fact.  You have a simple pole (thanks mrf) there.

{As originally asked, the McLaurin's series is not useful here because of that singularity.  I suggest you expand it around z = 1, which will give you a sensible series.  It will be convergent in a circle of radius 1 about z = 1.}

To find the Laurent series for your function, begin by removing the pole at 0.  You do this by multiplying the whole thing by z.  Now expand the new function in a Taylor's series.  I recommend doing it by calculus method, taking the various derivatives at 0 to get the coefficients of your Taylor's series.

When you've got the Taylor's series, divide the whole thing by z and you are done.

Comment: But I don't understand, McLaurin series exists, right? My task is to find it, so I guess it is possible somehow.

Comment: $z=0$ is a simple pole, **not** an essential singularity.

Comment: @mrf Thank you for pointing this out.  I saw the $e^z$ and didn't think further.